# replacing eval in privately scoped variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, scope

I'm trying to remove the eval statement in this function. I'm used to the this[whatever] style replacement but it doesn't work out in this instance.
Have a look:

```
var App = (function(fw) {
    var somevar1 = "hello";
    var somevar2 = "world";
    this.get = function(what) {
        return eval(what);
    }
});

var app = new App({some: "thing"});

// now for the use:
console.log(app.get("somevar1"),app);​
```

In the function, all my normal "eval scrubbing" options are not working for instance, I cant use:

```
 return this[what]
 return [what]
 return app[what]
 return new Function(what);
```

surely this isn't an odd case where eval is necessary? .. ps I have to note that I CANNOT rescope the variables inside App as it's part of a huge codebase.

Here's something to fiddle with:

http://jsfiddle.net/xAVYa/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're out of luck; `eval` is *the only thing that can access variables like that*. Next time, don't do things that way :)

You can start a migration by keeping a `data` object:

```
var App = (function(fw) {
    var data = {
        somevar1: "hello",
        somevar2: "world"
    };

    this.get = function(what) {
        return data[what];
    };
});
```

And just gradually do this across the entire codebase where you see it. It shouldn't break anything.

Comment: lol..... sadly it's a project I'm extending... I wouldn't have done it myself ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access an arbitrary local variable by string name without eval.  So, unless you're willing to change how those variables are accessed by other code inside of the `app` function, you will have to stick with eval (as ugly as it seems).

If, on the other hand, you're willing to change the code inside of the `app()` function that accesses `somevar1` and `somevar2`, then you have options.  Note, you shouldn't have to change anything outside the `app()` function because you can keep the same contract for the `.get()` function so this isn't one of those arbitrarily hard to find all possible places everywhere in the project that might be accessing these variables.  Because of the way they are currently declared, they can only be accessed directly from inside the `app()` function so your search/replace would be limited to that scope.

If it's OK for the variables to be properties of your object, you could do this:

```
var app = function(fw) {
    this.somevar1 = "hello";
    this.somevar2 = "world";
    this.get = function(what) {
        return this[what];
    }
};

var app = new App({some: "thing"});

// now for the use:
console.log(app.get("somevar1"));​
console.log(app.somevar1);
console.log(app["somevar1"]);
```

Comment: The question says "I CANNOT rescope the variables inside App as it's part of a huge codebase"

Comment: @icktoofay - I don't understand what "I CANNOT rescope the variables inside App" means exactly or why a change to this would be hard.  This is a relatively local change as only code inside the app object definition could have been accessing `somevar1` and `somevar2` before (as they were private to that scope) so one simple search and replace inside that object definition would find any of those references to change them to access as properties.  This is not the type of change that can affect far away code.

Comment: yep... I guess I've found that rare case where eval is actually my friend... Rescoping would take probably 2 days of solid work as modules from all over the place use the app.get function and there also app.set app.add etc. going to close this thread

Comment: @jfriend00: As the question said, the definition of `App` is huge. Furthermore, we don't know if any of the functions have a `this` that's not an `App`. (although you could introduce a variable to do that) Finally, there might be a lot of variables; you'd have to search and replace on each individually.

Comment: @icktoofay - but the accept answer has all of these issues too.  Every single reference to the variables inside of app has to get changed for the accepted answer too.  And, as you suggested, one could do `var appSelf = this` to overcome any embedded `this` references.

Comment: @Alex - this change doesn't change the interface to `.get()` at all so no clients of `.get()` or `.set()` have to change.  I think you're overestimating what it would take to clean this up.  Also, the accepted answer requires just as much cleanup as this one does as every reference to each variable inside of app has to be touched there too.

Comment: @jfriend00: The difference between the accepted answer and your answer is that the accepted answer admits that `eval` is the only way to do this without changing a lot more code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree, I'm just not sure what te full implications of exposing or rescoping all of these variables would be (there are some 1200+ private vars long story) I'm guessing that the original dev team had a good reason to keep these private so I'm giving up on replacing the eval...

Comment: @Alex - minitech's answer keeps them private.  Same amout of work as mine to fix the code.  The odd thing is the variables aren't really private in the original implementation since they can be retrieved by any code.  They are read-only if there's just a `.get()`, but you made reference to a `.set()` so if that exists, then they weren't private before anyway.

Comment: @jfriend00 yep, it's a weird system it checks the serialization of the caller and keeps guardian over manipulation of internals inside the app.get app.set... anyway. thanks for your time mate!

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a dynamic way to do this without eval. If the variables aren’t changing, though, you could try something like this:

```
var App = (function(fw) {
    var somevar1 = "hello";
    var somevar2 = "world";
    this.get = function(what) {
        switch (what) {
        case "somevar1":
            return somevar1;
        case "somevar2":
            return somevar2;
        }
    }
});
```