# What is the correct way of replacing eval() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I am using javascript [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP). For some reason, it is causing bugs, so I am replacing all eval. I have replaced this

```
var abc = "item." + str3 + ".power";
abc = eval(abc);
```

with

```
var abc = item[str3]["power"];
```

But I don't understand how do I replace these two statements?

```
1) setTimeout(eval(reloadfunction), 180000);

2) buttonrow = buttonrow + eval(button)(i, item);
```

reloadfunction is a variable which gets some string value which is a function name.
button is a variable which gets some string value and executes it as function and passes "i" and "item" which are other variables.

Comment: Since we don't know what `reloadfunction` or `button` are, it is rather hard to say. I'd guess the answer is "Stop writing your functions as strings and write them as functions instead".

Comment: It is probably something like `setTimeout(reloadfunction, 180000);`

Comment: "For some reason" -- that's the jist of `eval`.

Comment: Side note: Instead of `item[str3]["power"]`, it's customary to write `item[str3].power`.

Comment: @putvande, probably not. I'm willing to bet `reloadFunction()` returns Javascript code in a string.

Comment: eval(abc); returns undefined, so I don't think that abc = eval(abc); is what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [replacing eval in privately scoped variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986382/replacing-eval-in-privately-scoped-variables)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that's what I wanted to write. That boggles me. I do a lot of web development purely in fullstack JS and I have never once had to eval strings myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the variables and functions you are dealing with are global (ie. defined in the global scope) then you can use `window[reloadfunction]` and `window[button](i,item)`.

If they're locally scoped, however, you will have to completely restructure your code to have something like a map of functions:

```
var functions = {
    func1: function() {doSomething();},
    func2: function() {doSomethingElse();}
};
setTimeout(functions[reloadfunction],180000);
```

Comment: why not `func1:doSomething, func2:doSomethingElse` ? , and THEN execute ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Because I'm using `doSomething()` as a placeholder for actual code, but you could just refer to another function if you want.

Comment: oh ok missed that............

Answer (score 2):

I would use this :

`setTimeout( new Function(reloadfunction)  , 180000);`

since it runs in its own scope. ( not global , not current but its own)

p.s. you could set context also :

`new Function(reloadfunction).apply(t,[])` //immediate execute

`new Function(reloadfunction).bind(t,[])` //future execute (notice ie=>9)

as for comment : here is an example :

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think `reloadfunction` is a function body, but rather is a variable pointing to a function. *"reloadfunction is a variable which gets some string value which is a function name."*

Comment: I assume it's a string function something like `"alert(1)"`

Comment: I updated my comment to quote the question. Pretty sure it's meant to be a reference. However, what do you mean by "runs in its own scope (not global...)"? That's not right, unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @cookiemonster see my edit. `alert` run in the function's private scope

Comment: ...regarding your edit `.apply` couldn't be used there since it would be immediately invoked instead of passed to `setTimeout`. You'd need to wrap it in another function. And the function runs in the global scope, but it *creates* a new scope when executed, just like every function.

Comment: @cookiemonster yes. that's was a demonstration. I could use bind. ill clarify.

Comment: Yep, `.bind()` would be useful there.

Comment: @cookiemonster clarified :-)